# Web Scraping on Multiple Layers of a Website

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I have a question regarding web scraping on multiple layers of a website. For instance, I have a website about US elections having 2 layers.

Layer 1: state information: include 50 states.

Once I click each state on the table, I will jump into the Layer 2.

Layer 2: city information in each state

Once I click each city on the table, I will get the city mayor election result.

My purpose is to scrape all city mayor election data. Do you have any advice on how to scrape this multilayer webpage in Python?

There are limited resources online of scraping multilayer webpage. If you can provide any code examples, much appreciated!

My expected output:

| City     | Name     | Number of Votes
| -------- | -------- |---------------
| City A  | Tom      |    X
| City B   | Jerry   |    y
...        ...      ......

Comment: Write some code and go through the pages one after another? Also, check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For multilayer web scraping, you can use libraries like BeautifulSoup and Selenium in python. Start by scraping the first layer (state info) and collect links to each state. Then, iterate through these state links to scrape the second layer (city info), where you'll collect links to each city's mayor election results. Finally, navigate to each city link to scrape the mayor election data. You'll likely need to manage waits in Selenium for pages to load, especially if there's dynamic content. Unfortunately, without more specifics, I can't provide exact code, but this strategy should get you started!